# Estoy realizando una consulta e Intento actualizar mi código PHP a PHP PDO y no me muestra los registros

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi código **PHP** que deseo  actualizar.

```
     <?php 
    //Getting the requested Code
     $Code = $_GET['Code'];

     //Importing database
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating sql query with where clause to get an specific employee
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Code='$Code' ";

     //getting result 
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //pushing result to an array 
    $result = array();
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
     array_push($result,array(
    "Code"=>$row['Code'],
    "user"=>$row['user'],
    "Pass"=>$row['Pass'],
    "TipoUsuario"=>$row['TipoUsuario']
    ));

   //displaying in json format 
  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Este es mi código  **PHP** implementando *PDO*

```
       <?php
        try{
       $dsn = "mysql:host=fdb3.runhosting.com;dbname=698193_admin";
       $username = "698193_admin";
       $password = "1234admin";

     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    }
     catch(PDOException $e)
      {
       echo "No se pudo   conectar a  la base de  datos".$e- >getMessage();
       }

    try{
          $resultado = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE Code = :Code ");
          $resultado->execute('Code'=>$Code);
         $registro=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $json=json_encode($registro);
         return $json;
}
      catch(PDOException $e){
         echo "No existe  un registro  con dicho  código";
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Tu problema esta en la ejecución de la consulta preparada

Comment: Te faltan los dos puntos aquí: **resultado->execute(':Code'=>$Code);**

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo [@amenadiel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53754) el execute espera un array como parámetro, con tu comentario supongo que la versión de PHP que utilizas no soporta la sintaxis `[]`, intenta hacerlo con `array()`

```
$resultado->execute(array('Code'=>$Code));
```

Answer (score 0):

Según el manual [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) de PHP, tienes el placeholder mal escrito (faltan los dos puntos antes de `Code`). Además, los parámetros de `execute` deben ir como un array.

Entonces, reemplaza `$resultado->execute('Code'=>$Code);`
por `$resultado->execute(array(':Code' => $Code));` y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: ya  puse los   dos  puntos  como tú me  dices, aún así no me   muestra   los registros.

Comment: Error mío; debe ir en formato array: `$resultado->execute(array(':Code' => $Code));`

Comment: puedes editar la publicacion.

Comment: Editada; agregué algunos cambios para mejorar legibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo hacer la conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
$bd_config = array(
    'basedatos' => 'name',
    'usuario' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'pass'
);

function conexion($bd_config){
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
        return $conexion;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE Code = :Code');
$statement->execute(array(':Code' => $Code));
$resultado = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Has tu impresión de datos y listo.

Answer (score 0):

El execute espera un array como parametro, y tú le estás pasando algo que no es un array (de por sí es un error de sintaxis).

Prueba con

```
$resultado->execute([':Code'=>$Code]);
```

Comment: desde   mi navegador  ejecuto esta   consulta con lo  que  tú me dices  : http://ejemplo.atwebpages.com/conect/busquedaUser.php?Code=AB22  este es el error  que  me  muestra.Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /srv/disk2/698193/www/ejemplo.atwebpages.com/conect/busquedaUser.php on line 12

Comment: estarás usando php 5.2? Prueba la respuesta de @kacos

Answer (score 0):

con base a tu codigo  yo modificaria varias cosas.

1. colocar un die() en caso el PDO conexion falle
2. cerrar en un finally la conexion abierta
3. usar $resultado->bindparam(":Code ",$idapi); para agregar el
   parametro, recuerda que aparte de enviar el parametroe en el exccute
   estan varias opciones de como agregar los parametros

   ```
     try{
                       $dsn = "mysql:host=fdb3.runhosting.com;dbname=698193_admin";
                       $username = "698193_admin";
                       $password = "1234admin";

                       $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
                   }
                   catch(PDOException $e)
                   {
                       echo "No se pudo   conectar a  la base de  datos".$e->getMessage();
                       die();
                   }

                   try{
                       $resultado = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE Code = :Code ");
                       $resultado->bindparam(":Code ",$idapi);
                       if($resultado->execute()){
                           $registro=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                           $json=json_encode($registro);
                       }else{
                           $json = "Ocurrio Un error ejecutando sentencia";
                       }
                   }catch(PDOException $e){
                       echo "No existe  un registro  con dicho  código";
                   }finally {
                       $pdo = null;
                       $resultado = null;
                       return $json;
                   }
   ?>
   ```